# Best Practice to combine NHibernate.Search and ISession.Query<T> Options

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

I have a table look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]( 
        [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
        [UserID] [int] NOT NULL, 
        [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL, 
        [OrderDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
        [UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL, 
        [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL, 
        [Comment] [nvarchar](200) NULL, 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I used NHibernate to build search of order history, meanwhile I also 
leverage NHibernate.Search to search against Comment field (due to full 
text search reason).

I could build Linq query to search against UserID, ProductID, OrderDate 
fields and so on:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = orderRecordRepository.GetList(); 
orders = orders.Where(o => o.User.Id == 1 && o.Product.Id == 100 && 
o.OrderDate <= DateTime.Now);
```

Now I come with question that if I need to include Comment field 
search, I need to create another full text session like:

```
IFullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.session); 
return fullTextSession.CreateFullTextQuery<T>(fulltextQuery).List<T>();
```

The behavior of first query seems to be isolated from second one. if I 
need to search order with UserID, ProductID, OrderDate + some texts 
inside Comments, I have to perform 2 separated searches to obtain 2 
different lists and then find overlapped result to get final list. It 
seems to be very inefficient.

I am just wondering what is your practice in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as I understand it from your first query, you retrieve all Orders from the DB and filter them only at the application layer? that's not very efficient.
You could use Session.Query (in nH 3.0) or Session.Linq (with the nHibernate.Linq provider for older versions) to do the filtering at the DB level.
And, to answer your question- you can use .Contains in your Linq query to search according to text.

```
    IQueryable<Order> orders = session.Query<Order>; 
orders = orders.Where(o => o.User.Id == 1 && o.Product.Id == 100 && 
o.OrderDate <= DateTime.Now && o.Comments.Contains("kuku"));
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I may not make myself clear, I used NH Linq provider, the filtering is actually translated into SQL statement and done on SQL Server side. If I use SQL Server's fulltext search feature I can combine 2 searches together in one statement, but with NH + NH.Search(Lucene) for far I only can do 2 separated searches and merge result in application layer. That is the reason I am looking for some best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would add all the fields that I want to query on into the Lucene index, and then just query using full text search - the disadvantage is that you lose the ability to query via Linq.